# Module 'app_tracking_transparency' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apptrackingtransparency

flutter run works perfect,
flutter build iOS works perfect,

but when I archive through Xcode, build failed.

I need a solution that does not involve updating flutter. thanks

@import app_tracking_transparency; Module 'app_tracking_transparency' not found

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale es-419)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!